# Combine to Fields in one Qlik Sense Filter

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression, sqlike

I have 2 Fields and I need to combine them in one field. Is it possible to get this result in Qlik Sense?

[image: Fileds and Results]

I do not want concatenate but get the result in table

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly clear what the source is and how the data is structured, but you can `JOIN` without a key to flatten. Example:

```
[t1]:
LOAD * INLINE [
Activity
A
B];

[t2]:
LOAD * INLINE [
"Activity Code"
A01
B02];

[final]:
LOAD
    [Activity] AS [value]
RESIDENT [t1];

JOIN([final])
LOAD
    [Activity Code] AS [value]
RESIDENT [t2];

DROP TABLES [t1],[t2];
```

This will result in a table with the structure of:

| value |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| A01 |
| B02 |

Answer (score 0):

Levi's should be accepted as the answer but I just wanted to point out another option, which is to use the [CrossTable() prefix](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/crosstable.htm), which can be used to "pivot" the values of 2 or more columns into a single column. This method can be useful if the columns you need to combine are already in a single table.

The script you can use in the Data Load Editor may look like this:

```
[Table 1]:
Load * Inline [
Activity    ,   Activity Code
A           ,   A01
B           ,   A03
C           ,   A05
D           ,   B02
E           ,   B06
            ,   B03
            ,   C01
            ,   C03
            ,   C08
            ,   D24
            ,   D21
            ,   D30
            ,   E11
            ,   E15
            ,   E22
];


[Pivoted table]:
CrossTable ([throwaway 1], [Combined], 1)
Load
    1 as [throwaway 2]
  , [Activity]
  , [Activity Code]
Resident [Table 1];

Drop Fields [throwaway 1], [throwaway 2];
```

`[Table 1]` is just the data as it appears in your screenshot. Below that, the `[Pivoted table]` is a table that loads three fields:

- `1 as [throwaway 2]` - this is so that we have at least one qualifier field, or unchanged dimension, to group the combined columns on (see the [Qlik Help page on the CrossTable prefix](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/crosstable.htm) to read more about why this is needed). I named it `[throwaway 2]` because we won't need it after this.
- `[Activity]` - One of the columns we want to combine.
- `[Activity Code]` - The other column we want to combine.

The `CrossTable()` is going to result in an attribute field called `[throwaway 1]` (so named because we won't need it after this) and a data field called `[Combined]`, which will be our new combined field!

After we load this, our results are just what we'd expect:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense table with results of CrossTable prefix]